# how to add css sripts and jquery scripts to Laravel @extends('layouts.app') @section('content')

Tags: jquery, css, laravel-5

I need add following css and jquery scripts

```
<script src="{{('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.bxSlider.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#slider').bxSlider({
        ticker: true,
        tickerSpeed: 5000,
      tickerHover: true
      });
      });
    </script>

<link href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

to app.blade.php file

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="icon" href="{{asset('favicon.ico')}}">

        <title>Wealth </title>

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
        <link href="{{asset('css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="{{asset('js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js')}}"></script>

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <link href="{{asset('css/carousel.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

    <body>
        @yield('content')
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
        <!-- Just to make our placeholder images work. Don't actually copy the next line! -->
        <script src="{{asset('js/vendor/holder.min.js')}}"></script>
        <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
        <script src="{{asset('js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js')}}"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

and need above css and jquery pass to another blade file as @extends('layouts.app') and @section('content') how can do it??? without @extends('layouts.app') and @section('content') it is working but with @extends('layouts.app') and @section('content') it it not working.......

Comment: your question is very unclear

Comment: So, if you add the CSS and JQuery code underneath the `@yield('content') ` it is not passed when specifying `@extends('layouts.app')`? I think you are referring wrong to the layout file.

Comment: actually I cant understand what is the wrong. My menu bar include in app.blade.php file so, used @extends('layouts.app') to get menu for My every blade file. in this case I need create image slider with above jquery and css. it is working. but when I used @extends('layouts.app') and @section('content') tags it is not working. so, I think add jquery and css files to My app.blade.php file??? that is My problem

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has an undocumented feature called “stacks” in Blade templates. They allow you to define a section and “push” to it without having to constantly call `@parent` in `@section` tags (and override that section’s content).

Stacks look like this:

```php
<!-- resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>@yield('title', config('app.name'))</title>
        @stack('css')
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
        @stack('scripts')
    </body>
</html>
```

You can then append to this stacks like this:

```php
<!-- resources/views/some-view.blade.php -->
@extends('layouts.app')

@push('css')
    <link href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
@endpush

@push('scripts')
    <script src="{{('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.bxSlider.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#slider').bxSlider({
                ticker: true,
                tickerSpeed: 5000,
                tickerHover: true
            });
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

Answer (score 0):

`@yield('content')` is above your jquery. I'd advise adding more sections. wrap your scripts around `@section('scripts')` and a `@show`, in your sub view add `@section('scripts')`, `@stop` and add `@parent` inside. Repeat for styles. You have also added jQuery twice, here's how I'd do it:

Layout view:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
     <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
       <meta name="description" content="">
       <meta name="author" content="">
       <link rel="icon" href="{{asset('favicon.ico')}}">

       <title>Wealth </title>

       @section('styles')
         <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
         <link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

         <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
         <link href="{{asset('css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

         <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <link href="{{asset('css/carousel.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
      @show

       <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
       <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
       <script src="{{asset('js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js')}}"></script>



   <body>
       @yield('content')
       @section('scripts')
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
             <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
             <script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
             <!-- Just to make our placeholder images work. Don't actually copy the next line! -->
             <script src="{{asset('js/vendor/holder.min.js')}}"></script>
             <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
             <script src="{{asset('js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js')}}"></script>
       @show
     </body>
   </html>
```

Sub view:

```
    @section('scripts')
  @parent
      <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.bxSlider.js')}}"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#slider').bxSlider({
          ticker: true,
          tickerSpeed: 5000,
        tickerHover: true
        });
        });
      </script>
    @stop

@section('styles')
  @parent
  <link href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
@stop
```

`@parent` adds whatever is in your layout's block. adding a `@section` in your sub view would normally replace the layout's block with the sub block, this makes sure the sub view's block is appended instead.

### Edit

As discussed in the comments the problem was that jquery was included twice.

Comment: what did you mean as Sub view:

Comment: The view that has `@extends`

Comment: I remove **<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>** scripts from app.blade.php then it is working. any body can explain it?

Comment: You added jQuery twice

Comment: You're welcome =), could you please accept my answer if it helped? It might help other people in the future =)

Comment: this was help line **You added jQuery twice**